# Access to private tuple element through a template member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples

The class `foo` contains a private tuple member. I want to get reference to an element of this tuple using a `getElement<I>()`. I came to this solution but it doesn't work when the object is passed to the constructor of another class `bar`:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template<class... Args>
class foo {
    std::tuple<Args...> tup_;

    public:
    foo(Args... args) : tup_ {args...} {};

    template<size_t I>
    const typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Args...>>::type &
    getElement() const {return std::get<I>(tup_);}
};

template<class T>
class bar;

template<class T, class U>
class bar<foo<T,U>> {
    public:
    bar(foo<T,U> f) {
       auto j = f.getElement<0>(); // this is an ERROR!!! Line 22
    }
};


int main()
{
   foo<int, char> f(12,'c');
   auto j = f.getElement<0>(); // but this is OK!

   bar<decltype(f)> b(f);

   return 0;
}
```

compiler output:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'bar<foo<T, U> >::bar(foo<T, U>)':                                                                                                                                                                      
main.cpp:22:33: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token                                                                                                                                                              
        auto j = f.getElement<0>(); // this is an ERROR!!!                                                                                                                                                                       
                                 ^                                                                                                                                                                                               
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'bar<foo<T, U> >::bar(foo<T, U>) [with T = int; U = char]':                                                                                                                                        
main.cpp:32:24:   required from here                                                                                                                                                                                             
main.cpp:22:29: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'                                                                                                         
        auto j = f.getElement<0>(); // this is an ERROR!!!
```

Comment: `f.template getElement<0>();`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks, I didn't know about this syntax. but what does it mean to the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must warn the compiler that `getElement` is a template method. And to do it you must specify the `template` keyword, eg:

```
f.template getElement<0>()
```

This because otherwise the compiler tries to parse the code as `f.getElement < 0` so that it tries to call the binary `operator<` on `f.getElement` and `0` which is not what you want to do.